# Where do I start if I want to build an addon that uploads selected code to a server, in Visual C# Express/Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I had an idea just now and I think it's pretty good.

Select whatever code you want from your .cs/.vb file and on right click there will be an option that says 'Upload to PasteBin'.

Where would I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned Visual C# Express, that is quite limited in developing IDE add-ons, for that, you need the professional edition to do this.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Though for something as simple as "capture the selection and call a Web service," he might not even need an add-on: a macro might do the job (and could still be assigned to a menu).  Though an add-on would I think be required if he wanted to distribute it in a convenient form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [Tutorial : Creating Visual Studio Add-Ins](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/AddIns11292005015631AM/AddIns.aspx) and [Simpler Code Add-In for Visual Studio 2008](http://nayyeri.net/simpler-code-addin-for-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: @Rubens: Can you actually create an add-on with VS Express?

Comment: @tommieb75 - Nope, it's one of the main differences between the paid/free editions, +1

Comment: @Nick: You confirmed my answer above! :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your info, guys; I'll keep this answer anyways, ok?